# how to change the height of a single cell when clicked?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8, xcode6

I have to resize a single row of my tableView when clicked. How I can do this? Anybody could help  me?

My view controller class:

```
class DayViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var daysWorkPointTable: UITableView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var nipName = UINib(nibName: "daysWorkPointsCell", bundle: nil)

        self.daysWorkPointTable.registerNib(nipName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "daysWorkCell")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 75
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("daysWorkCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as daysWorkPointsCell

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

First you have to keep track of the indexPath of currently selected cell in a property:

```
var selectedCellIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
```

It should be an optional, because you can have no cell selected.
Next lets declare heights for selected and unselected state (change the values to whatever you want):

```
let selectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 88.0
let unselectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 44.0
```

Now you have to implement `tableView(_:, heightForRowAtIndexPath:)`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
        return selectedCellHeight
    }
    return unselectedCellHeight
}
```

Now in your `tableView(_:, didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` method you have to check wether the selected row or an unselected row has been tapped:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if selectedCellIndexPath != nil && selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
        selectedCellIndexPath = nil
    } else {
        selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
    }

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

    if selectedCellIndexPath != nil {
        // This ensures, that the cell is fully visible once expanded
        tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .None, animated: true)
    }
}
```

The `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` calls are giving you an animated height change.

If you want to change the duration of the height change animation you can wrap the `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` calls in an animation block `UIView.animationWithDuration(...)` and set it to whatever value you want.

You can check out [this sample project](https://github.com/kaiengelhardt/DynamicCellSelectionHeightExample) which demonstrates this code in action.

Comment: Argh, just read that you want this to work on just a single cell. My implementation is a little bit overkill, because it works for any number of cells.

Comment: I can't assign a value to the selectedCellIndexPath cause in the  validation if it is declared let, so I tried to change the let to var, but continue with error cause I can't assign nil to a NSIndexPath. Can you help me? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I changed the assignments to explicitly assign to self.selectedCellIndexPath. It should work now, hopefully ;).

Comment: After using beginUpdates() and endUpdates, scrollToRowAtIndexPath works fine.
But tableView.setContentOffset(_, animated:) do not work after calling that 2 methods! Any ideas why? Looks like a bug(((

Comment: As of Sept 2020, beginUpdates/endUpdates not only gives you animation but also is required for it to work