# How to add an image when a row is selected and then remove it when it is deselected in UITableView in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8, uiimage

I'm having an issue with making an image appear when a row is selected and then making the image disappear when another row is selected. If I touch a selected row it does not get deselected – this is OK as that is the behaviour that I want. I only want the currently selected row to be deselected when I touch another row.

I am writing in Swift.

I am using [Kai Engelhardt's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980386/kai-engelhardt) solution to expand the selected row, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918598/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-single-cell-when-clicked).

This UIImage should appear/disappear: **cellContent.ringImage.image = UIImage(named: "ring.png")**

I'm guessing that my logic is wrong in the **selectedCellIndexPath** part below.

This is my code:

In my TVC:

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController{

var selectedCellIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
let SelectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 222.0
let UnselectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 64.0

let menuItems = [
("1","test 1"),
("2","test 2"),
("3","test 3"),
("4","test 4"),
("5","test 5")]

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == menuTable {
        return menuItems.count
    } else {
            return 0}
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell
    if tableView == menuTable {
        let (my, section) = menuItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.myLabel.text = my
        cell.sectionLabel.text = section
        cell.selected = true
   }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    if let selectedCellIndexPath = selectedCellIndexPath {
        if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
            return SelectedCellHeight
        }
    }
    return UnselectedCellHeight
}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell
    var cellContent = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell
    let cellLabel = cellContent.sectionLabel.text

if let selectedCellIndexPath = selectedCellIndexPath {
        if selectedCellIndexPath != indexPath {
            self.selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
            cellContent.ringImage.image = UIImage(named: "ring.png")

        } else {
            self.selectedCellIndexPath != indexPath
            cellContent.ringImage.hidden = true
              tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        //    cellContent.testbutton.removeFromSuperView

        }
    } else {
        selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
        cellContent.ringImage.hidden = true
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()       
}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Mikee

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `self.selectedCellIndexPath != indexPath` does not do the deselect mark effect you want. You may try to use `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows()` to get the currently selected indexPath, compare it with the indexPath in the argument, and then complete your logic without assigning `self.selectedCellIndexPath`.

(Edited)
As I find that you also need the varialbe `self.selectedCellIndexPath` to identify the height, you could try to convert it to a counter variable which counts the selected time of currently selected row. If it is odd, it is selected, while when it's even that you know you would deselect it and reset the counter varialbe to zero.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    if (indexPath == tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows()[0] && self.counter % 2 == 1) {
    return SelectedCellHeight
    }
    return UnselectedCellHeight
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. When I replace my SelectedCellIndexPath code in heightForRowAtIndexPath with your code: if (indexPath == tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows()[0] && self.counter % 2 == 1) { I get an error "AnyObject is not convertible to NSObject", when I downcast as! NSObject I get an error "Could not find an overload for '==' that accepts the supplied arguments". If I remove [0] at the end of indexPathsForSelectedRows()[0] it compiles but does not expand the row size.

Comment: I have also removed the selectedCellIndexPath section and replaced it with: if tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() != indexPath {
            cellContent.ringImage.image = UIImage(named: "ring.png")
        } else {
            cellContent.ringImage.removeFromSuperview()
        }      This gives the same effect as currently have.

Comment: What about `(tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as! [NSIndexPaths])[0]` and then compare indexPath.row if it's a single selection tableView? `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows()` will return an array of Objects, and you should downcast here.