# changing cell height makes cell cover other cells swift uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I want cell to push others down when selected, like in Voice Memos app. but it covers other cells.

my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    UITableView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
        cell?.frame = CGRect(x: (cell?.frame.origin.x)!, y: (cell?.frame.origin.y)!, width: (cell?.bounds.width)!, height: 150)
    }
}
```

[before selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJn3Q.png)

[after selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIeY4.png)

how can it be done?

Comment: Don't need to change cell frame on click. You need to reload table cell and provide height which you expected for clicked cell. In this way, cell will not overlap another.

Comment: @Surjeet would you explain further with some code?

Comment: Refer to this answer for sample code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918598/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-single-cell-when-clicked

Comment: @Surjeet thank you.