# How do I change UITableViewCell height?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have implemented a tableview with a scrollview inside the cell. The cell consists of two views, the second view (shown in green) appearing after swiping:

[image: picture]

What I want to implement now is for the cell height to expand progressively as the cell is swiped to the right. So, as I begin to swipe the cell to the right and the green subview becoming visible on the main screen I want the cell to increase in height until the green subview is completely visible. Then as I swipe to the left, everything gets back to normal.

Since UITableViewCell conforms to the scroll view delegate, I suspect I write some code in my cell subclass - maybe use scrollViewDidScroll using the `contentOffset.y` of my scroll view.

Comment: One approach... Set up for auto-sizing cells, using the frame of your green subview to enforce the height. As you swipe (more likely, pan) to the right, scale `green` both width and height, and use `.beginUpdates()` and `.endUpdates()` to trigger the table redraw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example (Swift 3) of using auto-layout and auto-sizing cells. Not sure how you plan to "start" with the green view, so this demo initializes it to 40-pts wide (height is contained to 50% of the width).

You can simply create a new .swift file and paste this in, then add a UITableViewController in Storyboard and assign its class to `StretchCellTableViewController`. Everything else is created in code... no IBOutlets needed.

```
//
//  StretchCellTableViewController.swift
//  SWTemp2
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 6/22/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 DonMag. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class NonStretchCell: UITableViewCell {

    // pretty standard one-label cell

    var theLabel: UILabel!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupCell()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupCell()
    }

    func setupCell() {

        theLabel = UILabel()
        theLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: UIFontWeightLight)
        theLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.addSubview(theLabel)

        theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 6.0).isActive = true
        theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -6.0).isActive = true
        theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true

    }

}

class StretchCell: UITableViewCell {

    var stretchView: UIView!

    var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var scaleAction : ((CGFloat)->())?

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupCell()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupCell()
    }

    func setBarWidth(_ w: CGFloat) -> Void {
        widthConstraint.constant = w
    }

    func setupCell() {

        // instantiate the view
        stretchView = UIView()
        stretchView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stretchView.backgroundColor = .green

        // add it to self (the cell)
        self.addSubview(stretchView)

        // "pin" it to top, bottom and left
        stretchView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        stretchView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        stretchView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        // set height constraint to be 50% of the width
        stretchView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stretchView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true

        // instantiate the width constraint
        widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stretchView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)

        // needs priority of 999 so auto-layout doesn't complain
        widthConstraint.priority = 999

        // activate the width constraint
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([widthConstraint])

        // create a UIPanGestureRecognizer and add it to the stretch view
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didPan(sender:)))

        stretchView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

    }

    func didPan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let loc = sender.location(in: self)

        if sender.state == .began {

            // if you want to do something on drag start...
            //print("Gesture began")

        } else if sender.state == .changed {

            //print("Gesture is changing", loc)

            // update the width of the stretch view (but keep it at least 20-pts wide, so it doesn't disappear)
            // height is set to 1:1 so it updates automatically
            widthConstraint.constant = max(loc.x, 20)

            // call back to the view controller
            scaleAction?(widthConstraint.constant)

        } else if sender.state == .ended {

            // if you want to do something on drag end...
            //print("Gesture ended")

        }

    }

}


class StretchCellTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // array to track the bar widths, assuming we have more than one row with a bar
    // only a few rows will have the "stretch bar" - but for this example we'll just track a barWidth for *every* row
    var barWidths = [CGFloat]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80

        tableView.register(StretchCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "StretchCell")
        tableView.register(NonStretchCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "NonStretchCell")

        // init array for barWidths... initial value: 40, 30 slots
        barWidths = Array(repeating: 40, count: 30)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return barWidths.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // just make every 5th row a "Stretch" cell (starting at #3)
        if indexPath.row % 5 == 3 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StretchCell", for: indexPath) as! StretchCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .none

            // cells are reused, so set the bar width to our saved value
            cell.setBarWidth(barWidths[indexPath.row])

            // "call-back" function
            cell.scaleAction = {
                (newWidth) in
                // update the bar width in our tracking array
                self.barWidths[indexPath.row] = newWidth

                // disable Animations, because we're changing the size repeatedly
                UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)

                // wrap begin/end updates() to force row-height re-calc
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.endUpdates()

                // re-enable Animations
                UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
            }

            cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
            cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

            return cell
        }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NonStretchCell", for: indexPath) as! NonStretchCell

        // just for demonstration's sake

        if indexPath.row % 7 == 5 {
            cell.theLabel.text = "Row: \(indexPath.row) - This is just to show the text wrapping onto multiple lines. Pretty standard for auto-sizing UITableView cells."
        } else {
            cell.theLabel.text = "Row: \(indexPath.row)"
        }

        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

        return cell
    }

}
```

Result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As DonMag suggested you should trigger the height change by calling beginUpdates and endUpdates. Although not quite the same thing I implemented something very similar in this answer: [how to change the height of a single cell when clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918598/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-single-cell-when-clicked/24921181#24921181)

I am sure you can easily adapt it to your needs.

Comment: The method you link to will be tough to implement the way the question is asked. You are using two fixed-height values ***and*** requiring a call to `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. Much better to use auto-layout and constraints to auto-size the cell content.

Comment: OP was primarily asking for how to change the cell height. He never said he didn't have a fixed height or is using auto layout.

Comment: *"What I want to implement now is for the cell height to expand progressively as the cell is swiped to the right."* --- I'm not trying to argue with you, just trying to point the OP in the right direction. "... expand progressively ..." being the key part of the OP's description of what he/she wants to accomplish.